# Cocoapods can't be installed

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I want to develop a project for the ios platform and I have to install cocoapods to run it. but I tried to install cocoapods from the terminal and from the traditional way but no one works well and that error appears    [this error message appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqpjK.png)

what shall I do to solve this problem ??
[this error message appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aut5x.png)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have installed Ruby in your System

Run these commands from the terminal

1 - `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

2 - `brew install ruby` 
3 - `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
4 - `source ~/.bash_profile`

then open another terminal and type :
`gem install cocoapods --user-install`